# Beginner Java loop/array homework

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I have a homework question that needs some clarifications,

1.

```
public int f (int n) {
    if (n < 0)
      return 2;
    else
      return f (n - 1) + f (n - 3);
  }
```

what is the value when the recall is f(3)
I know that this loops
so

```
f(3) = f(2)+2
     = f(1)+2+2
     = f(0)+2+2+2
     = 8
```

but I'm not sure if Java considers 0 less than 0.

Comment: 0 is not less than 0. Be aware that a String of length 10 has a final index position of 9 since the String indices start from 0.

Comment: Why don't you run your program and see what output you get?

Comment: 0 is not less than 0. That's not even logical if you say it out loud...

Comment: @David Wallace I just started Java so I don't know how to run the program.

So in other words I have to go one step further?

Comment: OK, does your computer have either Eclipse, or IntelliJ or NetBeans on it?

Comment: +1 for the writing out of the recursion steps.

Comment: @David Wallace Yes I just downloaded it.

Comment: Then now would be a fantastic time to crack open the documentation and find out how to use it.  I could tell you the answer to both your questions, sure, but wouldn't it be more useful to you to be able to experience first hand what both Java programs will do?

Comment: If you are stuck without an ide and compiler, note that there are some [online compilers](http://ideone.com/MBLSjI) which you can use to verify your answers (No cheating! :)). e.g. `f(0) is 4.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is not less than 0.  It is equal to 0.  Use `<=` for "less than or equal to".

```
f(3) = f(3-1) + f(3-3)
f(3) = f(2) + f(0)

f(2) = f(2-1) + f(2-3)
f(2) = f(1) + f(-1)

f(1) = f(1-1) + f(1-3)
f(1) = f(0) + f(-2)

f(0) = f(-1) + f(-2)
f(N<0) = 2
```

Work your way back up.

```
f(0) = 2+2
f(1) = 2+2 +2
f(2) = 2+2+2 +2
f(3) = 2+2+2+2 +2+2
```

Answer (score 3):

Java does not consider 0 less than 0.

Arrays use a zero-based numbering system, so the last index is going to be the length of the array (the initialized size, 10 in this case) minus one. This is essentially a left-shift from

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

to

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

So

```
names[names.length] = "Hello";
```

will throw an exception, as names.length will get the number of **elements** in the array, but will not get the last **index** in the array.